# Status bar notification plugin error with Cordova

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to add the Status Bar Notification Plugin for Cordova to my Android App, but I get an error with it's code.

Here's the problematic code:

```
  Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
    .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
    .setContentText(contentText)
    .setSmallIcon(icon)
    .build();
```

The error is on the `.build()`, Eclipse tells me:

> "The method build() is undefined for the type Notification.Builder"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am having the same issue. It looks like a mismatch the sdk versions and now depreciated methods.

getNotification() is the method to call since API 11
build() was added in API 16

if you are like me, you are using a version < 16, so use .getNotification() instead.

Im not going to worry about API 16 right now but I bet if I download 16 and set my target to such, build() will work.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you! And yes I was targetting API 15. Now it works perfectly.

Comment: even after using .getNotification() the error in .java file is gone for me but plugin is not working.

Comment: @CodeGuru You also have to modify the javascript file, I think it was made for an old version of cordova. You can use the following code:
window.notify = function(title, body) {
    cordova.exec(null, null, 'StatusBarNotification', 'notify', [title, body]);
};

window.clear = function() {
    cordova.exec(null, null, 'StatusBarNotification', 'clear', []);
}

And then just call the notify or clear functions from your code.

Answer (score 1):

For me .getNotification() didn't resolve the problem, because I need a solution for API 10 and higher.

I found a way to deal with it. If someone else has the same issue, I recommend to do this :

1) Go through instructions for StatusBarNotification ([click](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/StatusBarNotification))

2) Modify StatusBarNotification.java

- Add

> private Notification noti;
>
> private PendingIntent contentIntent;
>   
>   At the bottom of StatusBarNotification class, for example before NotificationManager declaration

- Modify showNotification method

Comment or delete:

```
import android.app.Notification.Builder;
```

and

`Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
.setContentTitle(contentTitle)
.setContentText(contentText)
.setSmallIcon(icon)
.build();`

Instead of this part, paste:

```
noti = new Notification(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on, contentText, System.currentTimeMillis() );
noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;


Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, !yourMainActivityClass!.class);
notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
notificationIntent = notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

noti.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
```

- Change !yourMainActivityClass! to your class
- Add calling method in index.html For tests you can make JQM button with

  > onclick='window.plugins.statusBarNotification.notify("Put your title
  >   here", "Put your message here");return false;'

I know that this solution is using depreciated methods, but I spent a lof of hours to make it works and I didn't see another solution for API 10. If somebody has better idea, share with me ;)